# How to request a package be upgraded?

Tags: updates

How do I request a package in the official Canonical maintained Ubuntu repos be upgraded?

Comment: I think you can't. The upgrade will be pulled into the repository when it's ready, at least for the next release it should be there. Unless it's a security update, of course, that goes faster.

Comment: Try https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates.

Comment: Is your question about upgrading a package in the development release, or in an already released Ubuntu version?

Comment: I want Chromium to be updated from version 51 to 52, a stable version has already been released by Google but the Ubuntu repos have yet to include it. A lot of people are having trouble with scroll jumping and 52 fixed it.

Comment: @PeterBucher So your question is not specific enough. Why didn't you just ask about upgrading Chromium from the get-go?

Comment: even then ...  why would we accept unstable versions of chromium?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's not stable yet and I found a beta repo which has the version I need:
https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-beta
Sorry about that.